# Atlas MongoDB connection with Lambda via VPC not works

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, lambda, vpc

I try to connect my MongoDB on Atlas with Lambda functions.

I did everything from instruction https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/ but I got error:

`Task timed out after 30.03 seconds`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Please create Gateway VPC endpoint and update it route tables

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html

Answer (score 0):

For other people are who facing this problem, it might be an issue related to your cluster type

Network peering connection is only supported on dedicated tiers (M10 and above)

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-vpc-peering/